# Issue with importing Custom Scala Jar

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, eclipse-luna

I have few Scala projects which uses some common functionalities.

So for better maintenance, I have create a common project P1 with all the common functionalities and created the jar.

Then I have added the jar as external dependency to my all other projects.
After importing the necessary classes from the jar, in my class, I see no error in eclipse.

But when I am trying to build the Jar for these other projects, it throws error saying : class/object that I am trying to import not found.

Surprisingly, when I am pointing the mouse to the functions that I am using from that external jar, it shows me the function signature accurately. 
But somehow, the jar building is failing.
Any help?

I am using Eclipse Luna for Scala, Scala 2.11.8 in Windows 7 .

Comment: Since you added P1 as external dependency using eclipse, it is added using eclipse project configuration so when you open the project with eclipse, P1 will be added to the eclipse project classpath as an extra dependency. But the jar creation is not done by using eclipse project configuration and is done by the build tool which can be sbt, gradle or maven. And your build tool configuration still has no idea about the existence of this P1 jar hence the build tool will fail to compile the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to resolve the issue after after installing the jar using mvn and adding the dependency in pom.